# 'android.os.AsyncTask' is deprecated in a register Activity, Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, http, android-asynctask

I´m did a register activity, in this activity I've two spinner one to state and other to city,the activity send the string of the spinner of state to phpfile and this return all the cities of this state and in the java fill the spinner with this cities, I use AsyncTask with a class to do the query to my php file in http server and I get this error in all the class 'android.os.AsyncTask' is deprecated.

Someone can help me or orientedme to fix that.

```
private class GetModelFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(registro.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Fetching Data");
                pDialog.show();
    
            }
    
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                estado = spinnerEstado.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Handler jsonParser = new Handler();
                String json = null;
                try {
                    json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall("https://chilaquilesenterprise.com/localidades/get_model.php?nombre_estado="+ URLEncoder.encode(estado,"UTF-8"), Handler.GET);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    
                Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);
                if (json != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                        if (jsonObj != null) {
                            JSONArray model = jsonObj
                                    .getJSONArray("nombre");
    
                            for (int i = 0; i < model.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject modObj = (JSONObject) model.get(i);
                                Nombre nom = new Nombre(modObj.getString("nombre"));
                                nombreList.add(nom);
                            }
                        }
    
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
    
                }else {
                    Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
                }
    
                return null;
            }
    
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                populateSpinnerModel();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can move to other alternatives like Kotlin Coroutines, AsyncTask is deprecated in Android API 30, You can still use it (Suppress the Warning) but there won’t be any development on that.

Comment: Use an Executor.  You should never have been doing networking on an AsyncTask anyway, as the shared thread nature of them by default means multiple AsyncTasks can starve waiting on network IO.  Yes, I know lots of example code does it, that doesn't mean its good code.